# How to fit the <object> video to the parent container's width and height

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

```
<div id="player" width='2000px' height='600px'>
<object  id="pl" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
    <param name='url' value='Video/3.mp4'/>
    <param name='ShowControls' value='-1' />
    <param name='ShowDisplay' value='-1' />   
    <param name='ShowStatusBar' value='-1' />
    <param name='stretchToFit' value='0' />
    <param name='uiMode' value='none' />  
</object>
 </div>
```

how can I fit the video's width and height to the container "player" ?
I want to stretching the video.

Comment: `width: 100%; height: 100%` in CSS?

Comment: Or perhaps stretchToFit' value='1'

Comment: i have try stretchToFit attribute , but it doesn't work , i don't know this attribute work in which condition.

Answer (score 0):

It works with the following CSS lines:

```
#player {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 600px;
}
#pl {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Attention, you set a `width` and a `height` attributes on a `div` element.
This will not work, you can only size a `div` element with CSS rules or via the `style` attribute.

You can play with my solution on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzi/dqLwy/).

Cheers,
Thomas.

Comment: the "pl"'s width is 2000px , but the video we can see is also smaller than the 2000px

Comment: In the example I gave, the `#pl` element has a width of 2000px: http://fiddle.jshell.net/tzi/dqLwy/show/

Comment: Are you sure it smaller than 2000px on your computer? Wich browser do you use?

Comment: IE11, the video's actual width is smaller than 2000px,but the height is 600px , the video seems keep its original ratio ..

Comment: I tried on IE11 and it's ok. You see on the following screenshot, the screen is 1280px and the scrollbar is a bit bigger than the half of the screen: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/627x512q90/69/t3pu.png the

Comment: wow,i see it,i use your code in my browser, it doesn't work... confuse about it , have you try use classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" for the mediaplayer?

Comment: No, I didn't use your code. The last HTML element is object, so it is also the last element that you can style with CSS. So if it works with YouTube and doesn't work with your object, you probably have no CSS solution. Sorry.